# jQuery form. Why to use it?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I wanted to ask, why is it good or better to have a script print the form than plain html. And what's the difference? When I type:

```
<form><input type="button" value="button" /></form>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $form = $("<form></form>");
     $form.append('<input type="button" value="button" />');
     $('body').append($form);
</script>
```

What if user disables javascript in his browser?

For security, is the plain html and php enough or should I use javascript to build and validate the registration form?

Comment: i would always do the former unless I need the functionality of the latter

Comment: What makes you think using JS would be more secure?

Comment: I read somewhere, that I should always generate form using JS/jQuery. Otherwise it's open to bots.

Comment: @jevniky in that case it would be better to inject a hidden field with a value retrieved through a rest web service in json that temporarily stores it in a table i.e form_keys so you can later in your business logic validate it. I do that all the time, it's much more user friendly than captcha

Comment: @jevniky what you are btw doing over there doesn't stop any bot. Any bot that knows that there is a form there can just submit a form made by itself.

Comment: Can you give me an example please? Of that hidden field. I never worked with JSON so far.

Comment: That has nothing to do with JSON. Just do `$('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="check" value="ok">')` and in PHP check that the value was sent. Note that this will also exclude people with JS disabled.

Comment: @jevniky If you wait one second I'll put what i have as an answer

Comment: @Juhana that doesn't make sense. I can create a script that posts 1000 forms in one minute containing a variable containing the the value OK

Comment: @bicycle Sure, but it will stop most spam bots that aren't targeting specifically your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start with your first question .
It's better to make forms in HTML , because in case of disabling the javascript your costumers will get problem using your application .

Secons Question :
Better to use PHP validation , because the javascript can be fooled by a person with basic hacking skills . for exemple after disabling the JavaScript your validation script won't work .

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to generate it with Javascript, all you did was to make it much, much more hard to maintain. When you need to change the form html, it is **really annoying** to deal with Javascript string literals.

Answer (score 1):

I use to skip form tags altogether, they are ugly, you can only have one action, and you cannot nest them. Instead I use ajax postings in for instance onclick handlers and reload the webpage if necessary in the success handlers of those:

```
var data = {formvar1:3, formvar2: "foo"};
$.post('/foo/bar.php', data, function(webpage)
{
  location.reload();
});
```

or if the ajax handler returns json:

```
var data = {formvar1:3, formvar2: "foo"};
$.post('/foo/bar.php', data, function(result)
{
  if (result.success)
  {
    alert("nice work!");
    location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
    alert(result.message);
  }
}, 'json');
```

Oh, my answer came a bit late so you are free to ignore it. I never care about people disabling javascript because I think they are a myth btw :)

(It is worth mentioning that this stuff requires including jquery)

Comment: +1 true, only search engines and developers checking their website works without js are the people that have js turned off

Answer (score 0):

So like i said this is one way to prevent bots from spamming you. It will stop most bots. After implementing this I never had a problem with bots anymore

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `key_validation` (
  `key` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `key` (`key`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**PHP REST Web Service (getKey.php)**

```
<?php
//file that creates a connection to the database
require "db_connect.php";


if($_GET['mode'] == "get_key") {
  $key = md5(microtime().rand());

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO key_validation (`key`,`date`) VALUES ('$key','".time()."')");

  echo json_encode($key);
  exit();
}

?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function insertKeyIntoForm(form) {
    $.getJSON('getKey.php?mode=get_key', function(data) {
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            id: 'verify_key',
            name: 'verify_key',
            value: data
        }).appendTo(form);
    });
}
insertKeyIntoForm('#myFormId');
```

**PHP File the processes the registration**

```
//TODO
//permanently block ip addresses that requests this service more than x number of times a minute

function func_query_first_cell($query) {
    if ($p_result = mysql_query($query)) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_row($p_result);

    }
    return $result[0];
}

      //to make sure is no spammer
  if(func_query_first_cell("SELECT `key` FROM key_validation WHERE `key`='$verify_key'") == "")
    exit();

  else
    db_query("DELETE FROM key_validation WHERE `key`='$verify_key'");
```